# Error invoking LaTeX from within WinEdt

Tags: errors, compiling, winedt

[image]

this is my work environment...

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. Please change the title of your question as it's misleading, as well as the tag 'bibtex' (probably)

Comment: Where do you import this? In the first line of the document? That's really an error. But other errors lurk in the background

Comment: the error addresse the syntex1

Comment: Your comment does not really clearify the question

Comment: i'm not sure tex code is going to help figure out what was going wrong, since this looks like the remnants of a command launched either from the command line or more likely a script from an editor interface.  we really need to know *exactly* what was your environment and what you were doing that resulted in this error.

Comment: yes I think this is correct barbara if problem be your statement what should I do for resolve it ? of course I try to send the image from my inveroment now.

Comment: the visual you've provided identifies the environment as winedt.  i'm not a winedt user, so i can't help, but i've added the [winedt] tag to the question in the hope that someone more knowledgeable will notice it, and i'm about to change the title too..

Comment: I will think the problem is not the code, it's the editor. You should review the configuration editor to work well with LaTeX.

Comment: Hi  G. Aguilera I do it several times but don't yield any result.probably I can't find origin of error specifically.

Answer (score 2):

As you can see from the command line, you've pressed the button 'PDFLaTeX' but you're invoking `winedt.exe` instead of `pdflatex.exe`.

This means that you've made a mess with your configuration.

First of all, be sure that you have a TeX distribution installed, either [MiKTeX](http://www.miktex.org/) ot [TeX Live](https://www.tug.org/texlive/).

Then, in WinEdt, go to 'Options' -> 'Execution Modes'.

There, press the 'Default' button as indicated in the picture below.

[image]

In this way, WinEdt should be able to retrieve all the informations about your TeX distribution automatically.

If it doesn't, click on the tab page 'Diagnosis' for a complete diagnosis of your system. There WinEdt will inform you about all the things you're missing in your configuration.